# How to properly include a Razor class library using SignalR into a MAUI Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, maui, razor-class-library

My requirement is to reuse a razor component, which uses SignalR from a razor class library inside a Blazor Server app and a MAUI Blazor app. The MAUI app is only supposed to run on Windows.

The Namespace.UI.Components csproj looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>false</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="7.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I can reference and use it perfectly in the blazor application.
However, if I use the code in my MAUI blazor application like so:

```
<Chat HubUrl="@_hubUrl" />

@code {
    private string _hubUrl = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _hubUrl = configuration.Get<AppSettings>()!.HubUrl;
    }
}
```

I receive the error `There was no runtime pack for <RuntimePack> available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier '<RID>'.` where `<RuntimePack>` is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `<RID>` is

- android-arm
- andoid-arm64
- android-x64
- android-x86
- iossimulator-64
- maccatalyst-x64

I can remove those errors by removing the targets in my MAUI csproj: `<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>`

But then I receive the error `MSB4057: The target '_GenerateAppxPackage' does not exist in the project.`, if I try to publish the application.

There must be a caveat that I am missing and am happy for any assitance on how to make that scenario work. I'd avoid duplicating code in my MAUI project, if I can, jsut because a RCL does not really work.

Comment: You can go through [Use ASP.NET Core SignalR with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server). Also, there is a [sample app MauiSignalRGridDemo](https://github.com/Eilon/MauiSignalRGridDemo) combining .NET MAUI, Blazor, and SignalR, to build a native client app that receives real-time updates from a server, you can refer to it.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT That is missing the point. I have all the signalR client related code inside a RCL, not inside the MAUI project. Putting it inside the MAUI project defeats the purpose of reusing it across multiple applications.